# How do I push notifications if my app hasn't been run yet?

Tags: ios, delphi, push-notification, delphi-xe4, delphi-xe5

Assuming the user has *not* launched your app yet, **but it has been run before**. Is there a way to still "push" news/updates?

To explain what I mean:
Imagine the user installed "your-restaurants-in-your-area" local orientated app, and configured the app in some setting to notify the user when new restaurants open... However, the user forgets to run this app at a daily basis. Is there a way for the app to auto-show news inside iOS?

I have found this for XE4 where Anders is stying to help people get it working with XE4
http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2013/05/02/39456

http://blogs.embarcadero.com/ao/2013/05/24/39472

After further searching (I missed this first round) I found this:

http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/43239

It requires editing Delphi XE4 bundled source files (i.e. so it is not officially supported / made easy in XE4), but it seems it can be made to work. (I have not found any official mention of official "built-in" support in XE5.)

I upvoted the answer given sofar since it was helpful in a way.

Comment: It seems to me that your question is not (yet) about Delphi, and you need to do some research to see if **iOS** supports that functionality in the first place. If you determine it does, you can then research how that is done in non-Delphi code, try to figure out how to implement it in Delphi, and **then** post a question that includes that effort and asking how to make it work. So far, I see nothing that indicates you've done any of that yet.

Comment: I knew it could be done because I have seen it in an iOS app. Perhaps my explanation was clumsy because I can see some thought I meant the app had never been run. Anyhow, I can see it can be "hacked" in XE4. I have not found info for XE5.

Comment: Your first sentence sais "is there a way", which doesn't sound like you knew it could be done (and thus my comment). It doesn't change the rest of what I wrote, however. :-)

Comment: I was not sure if it could be done in Delphi. I hope it makes sense. I tagged my question Delphi-XE4 and Delphi-XE5. However, it is true I do not know at present how to code it in ObjectiveC/XCode either. Anyhow, the video I found is probably the best bet.

Comment: For any question of the form "How do I do *X* in language *Y*?" when *Y* is a newcomer to a relatively mature field, assume the answer is "The same way you do it in any other language." Go research how to do *X* in the field's "native" language, and then translate. If you have trouble, then ask, but explain how far you got in the translation, too. Otherwise, you're just going to get the same answer again.

Answer (score 4):

The question is not related to Delphi…

1. It is impossible to auto-run/unattended-run applications in iOS.
2. If the user has never opened your application, you will not able to send him “Push notification”, because your application must be registered with the token. Usually the application registers on the start.
3. Let’s assume the user launched the application at least once, and your application successfully registered the token for “Push notification”.  In this situation, you will able to notify the user when the new restaurant will be opened.
4. The problem in this situation that you don’t know the physical location of the user. Maybe you can add the region of interests in your applications, so you will know to whom to send the notification.

Comment: At least a civil attempt to answer some of the parts of the multi-question.